# Standardization — Normalisation

Tags: discussion, language, formatting, quotation-marks

Reading [Jefromi's question](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/why-are-there-so-many-trivial-edits), I have been concerned with these edits, especially because of their nature. For example, a lot of these edits are only adding a space before a question mark. I am a native French speaker, living in Canada, studying translation and therefore French usage and style. Where I live, it is recommended to *not* have a space before a question mark, among other punctuation marks.

As the site grows, there will be more and more users from different countries around the world. Given that each region has its own usage and style, **should French Language & Usage require all questions and answers to follow France's usage, or should we allow all French speakers to write as is correct for them?**

**Edit:** Relatedly, should a post that is consistent and conform to a particular style be edited to conform to another style?

For example:

- Should italics be removed or added (e.g. Why do we use "schnookums"?  <->  Why do we use *schnookums*?);
- Should bolding be removed or added;
- Should curly English quote be changed to straight or vice versa?

---

En lisant la [question de Jefromi](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/why-are-there-so-many-trivial-edits), j'ai trouvé que les révisions dont il est mention étaient préoccupantes, principalement en raison de leur nature. À titre d'exemple, bon nombre de ces révisions ne consistent qu'à ajouter une espace avant un point d'interrogation. Je suis francophone, je vis au Canada et j'étudie en traduction, je connais donc les usages et les normes de la langue française. Ici, l'usage est de ne *pas*  mettre d'espace avant un point d'interrogation, entre autres marques de ponctuation.

Au fur et à mesure que le site prendra de l'ampleur, il y aura de plus en plus d'utilisateurs de différents pays partout dans le monde. Compte tenu du fait que chaque région a son propre usage et ses propres normes, **le site French Language & Usage devrait-il exiger que toutes les questions et les réponses suivent les normes de la France, ou devrait-on permettre à tous les francophones d'écrire selon leur usage correct?**

**Révision** : Corollairement, est-ce qu'une question ou une réponse qui est consistante et conforme à un certain style devrait être révisée pour adhérer à un autre style?

Par exemple :

- Est-ce que des italiques devrait être ajoutées ou enlevées (p. ex. Pourquoi utiliser « tralala »? <-> Pourquoi utiliser *tralala*?);
- Est-ce que des caractères gras devraient être ajoutés;
- Est-ce que, le cas échéant, des guillemets courbés devraient être remplacés par des guillemets droits ou vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posts can be in any dialect of French (or English), with the limitation that idioms that aren't widely understood should be avoided. The situation is similar on English-speaking Stack Exchange sites: [both British and US spelling are accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109025/what-constitutes-acceptable-english-on-se-sites), but [Indian idioms get poor reception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109025/what-constitutes-acceptable-english-on-se-sites). We should not edit a post that is correct in one variant of French to make it conform to some other variant of French. For example, Swiss or Canadian spacing around punctuation is fine. However, it's ok to edit a post for internal consistency.

That rush of additions of spaces before the final `?` in a question title is a bit special: [there used to be a bug that prevented the asker from putting a space even if he so desired](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/why-is-se-engine-removing-spaces-before-question-marks-in-titles-please-make-it).

---

Les messages peuvent être dans n'importe quel dialecte du français (ou de l'anglais), en faisant attention tout de même à éviter les idiomes qui ne sont pas largement compréhensibles. La situation est similaire sur les sites anglophones de Stack Exchange : [l'orthographe britannique et l'orthographe américaine sont acceptées](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109025/what-constitutes-acceptable-english-on-se-sites), mais [certains idiomes indiens passent mal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109025/what-constitutes-acceptable-english-on-se-sites). Nous ne devrions pas éditer un message qui est correct dans une variante du français pour le faire conformer à une autre variante. Par exemple, l'espacement canadien ou suisse autour des signes de ponctuation n'est pas un problème. Par contre, on peut éditer un message pour qu'il soit cohérent dans son usage.

La vague d'ajouts d'espaces avant le `?` final du titre des questions est un peu particulière : il y avait un bug, maintenant corrigé, qui empêchait le posteur de mettre une espace même s'il le voulait.

Comment: Merci, j'avais du mal à le dire aussi clairement.

Comment: Quid des éditions pour rendre une question et ses réponses cohérentes ensemble ?

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Je ne vois pas pourquoi le faire, ce sont des personnes différentes avec des styles différents. Sinon il faudrait tous changer notre style personnel à celui de l'auteur de la question.

Comment: @Kareen: Bon point.