# Style changing edits

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standardization - Normalisation](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305/standardization-normalisation)

Considering that [we should not edit a post that is correct in one variant of French to make it conform to some other variant of French](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/306/217), **should we edit a post that is correct in one style variant to make it conform to some other style variant?**

For example:

- Should italics be removed or added (e.g. Why do we use "schnookums"?  <->  Why do we use *schnookums*?);
- Should bolding be removed or added;
- Should curly English quote be changed to straight or vice versa?

Note: this question is asked with regards to both English and French posts on FL&U.

Comment: This was raised again [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7167602#7167602).

Answer (score -2):

My point of view on this topic is still the same

> if an edit appeals someone while not hurting others, just let it be.

So if someone edit your post in a way you find not appropriate, you are entirely right to rollback and complain. But if someone likes to prettify the posts, if there is no conflict, why should we bother? Lay back, live and let live.

So, to make myself clear: **we should do whatever appeals us, provided that it doesn't harm anyone¹.**

And for the word-of-god worshippers, see https://french.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

> If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

---

¹ And is on-topic, of course.

Comment: I didn't ask if the edits should be rolled back if they weren't liked, I asked if they should be made *in the first place*.

Comment: I thought that was obvious: why should we forbid/discourage them?

Comment: So what happens when different things appeal to different people, provided that they're both correct and on-topic? An edit war?

Comment: In that case, everyone is civil enough to stop the edit war and rollback to before the edit war. Or the mods make them civil enough. But have you seen it here yet? So why bother now?

Comment: You should only edit if you make the post better, not if you change from one typographical convention to another typographical convention..

Comment: @Evpok Perhaps it's not a problem now simply because we're lucky enough that not a lot of people are doing it and that those other people who do disagree don't edit back.

Comment: @Kareen So let's just refrain from knee-jerk policy-making and wait until there is a real need.

Comment: @Gilles Define *better*. This is not going anywhere, you should only edit if **you think** that it makes the post better. And try to discuss with those who disagree instead of bluntly rolling back.

Comment: @Gilles It seems that you don't quite agree with this answer. Would you mind formulating an answer reflecting the whole of your thoughts?

Comment: @Kareen I don't have anything to add to [my previous answer](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/305/standardization-normalisation/306#306).

Comment: @Gilles Then I suggest maybe editing that question to include this one, closing this one as duplicate and merging the two. This way we can have everything relevant on the same page.

Comment: @Kareen Ok, go ahead and edit your question if you like.

Comment: @Gilles All right, it's done.