# Quelles sont les conventions typographiques ayant cours sur french.SX ?

Tags: discussion, typography

J'ai pu remarquer que nous étions plusieurs à être à cheval sur la typographie. Cependant, nous ne semblons pas tous nous baser sur les mêmes conventions.

J'ai pu voir par exemple aujourd'hui deux éditions qui ont mis en italique des mots entre guillemets. En ce qui me concerne, l'italique s'applique à l'emphase et aux mots étrangers, pas systématiquements aux mots français cités.

### Avons-nous un standard définissant les bonnes pratiques ou conventions à suivre en termes de typographie sur french.stackexchange ?

#### Si non, faudrait-il en établir ?

En ce qui me concerne, mes habitudes coïncident généralement avec [les recommendations de Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Conventions_typographiques#Mots_.C3.A9trangers) qui s'accordent avec la plupart des préconisations que j'ai pu voir ailleurs et ont l'avantage de s'appuyer beaucoup sur le [LRTUIN](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de convention typographique, autre que les règles typographiques françaises/locales (voir [cette question sur la normalisation](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/305/217)).

Pour l'utilisation de l'italique et des guillemets, c'est au choix. Je ne crois pas qu'il serait terriblement utile d'établir une convention de style pour l'ensemble du site; il n'y aurait que plus de travail à effectuer en modifications que pour une question stylistique.

Si vous avez un style particulier qui vous plaît, utilisez-le, mais évitez de modifier un post qui est grammaticalement correct et consistant pour adapter son style (utilisation des guillemets, de l'italique, etc.) au vôtre.

Comment: Je posais justement la question afin de ne pas démarrer une guerre d'edit qui n'aurait pas de sens.